# Cross account RDS and Secrets usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I am deploying AWS RDS in **account-a** using terraform-aws-rds module and setting the value of user and pass like below:

```
username = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.db_access.secret_string)["username"]
password = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.db_access.secret_string)["password"]
```

My data.tf looks like below:

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "sqlcreds" {
  name = format("/db/%s/sqlcreds",var.stage)
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "sqlcreds" {
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.sqlcreds.id
}
```

Secrets are stored in **account-b** with Secret name, arn as below

```
/db/dev/sqlpwd
arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<account-num>:secret:/db/dev/sqlpwd-**
```

How can I facilitate the communication cross account handshake between RDS and SECRETS using provider.tf? Is that the best way or any other easier approach?